Vectorising an iterative implied volatility function
I'd like to calculate the implied volatility (IV) of a table t containing an option chain.
The function to calculate the IV is:
// Newton-Raphson method to find implied volatility
impliedVol:{[S;K;T;r;isCall;marketPrice]
 sigma:0.5;  // Initial guess
 tolerance:1e-6;
 i:0;
 diff:1;
 while[abs[diff]>tolerance and i<100;
       result:.deriv.bsm[S;K;r;T;isCall;sigma];
       diff:result[`price]-marketPrice;
       sigma:sigma-diff%result[`vega];
       i+:1;
      ];
 sigma:$[i=100; 0N; sigma]
 };

The above function works OK for scalar inputs, however for using it inside a select statement it fails since it makes the variable diff a list (instead of scalar) presumed by the function. As a workaround I could do:
ivFunc:{[rate;row] impliedVol[row`S; row`K; row[`daysLeft]%365; rate; row`isCall; row`close]};
       t:update IV:100*ivFunc[rate] peach t from t

which despite peach is excrutiatingly slow.
How can i modify impliedVol so that I can write the following and thus expect vectorization to speed things through?
r:0.04;
t:update IV:100 * impliedVol[S;K;daysLeft%365;(count)#r;isCall;close];


I think there's going to be too many unknowns here for anyone to give a guaranteed speedup, for example are we to presume that the sub-function .deriv.bsm is also vectorised and efficient? Are you insisting on using .deriv.bsm or are you ok with someone writing entirely their own IV function? What data volume are we talking about, thousands of rows? Tens of thousands? Is there any repetition in the inputs or are they all unique?
